# Showing multiple data in select query in Sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have following query

```
SELECT  R.ServiceID,ItemName, Price 
FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=2264
```

and result yields

```
ServiceID   ItemName        Price
2264        LCD             1500.00
2264        Touch Panel     1200.00
2264        Service Charge  250.00
```

i want following result with three column without cursor.

```
2264   LCD,Touch Panel,Service Charge   2950
```

i have tried group by

```
SELECT  R.ServiceID,SUM(Price) as Price--,ItemName, Price 
FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=2264
GROUP BY R.ServiceID
```

results

```
ServiceID   Price
2264    2950.00
```

but cannot take itemname as comma seperated string.
Help me guys.

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Space seperated itemName will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple sql.

```
SELECT t.ServiceID, STUFF(
(

    SELECT ',' + s.ItemName FROM (SELECT  R.ServiceID,ItemName, Price 
    FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
    WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=2264) s
    WHERE s.ServiceID = t.ServiceID
    FOR XML PATH('')

),1,1,'') AS Items, sum(t.Price) as Price
FROM (SELECT  R.ServiceID,ItemName, Price 
FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=2264) AS t
GROUP BY t.ServiceID
```

output is :

`2264   LCD,Touch Panel,Service Charge  2950.00`

Answer (score 3):

Aggregate string concatenation is a bit of a pain in SQL Server.  You can do this as:

```
WITH r as (
      SELECT R.ServiceID, ItemName, Price 
      FROM RequisitionDetail RD JOIN
           Requisition R 
           ON RD.RequisitionID = R.RequisitionID
      WHERE RD.ItemStatus = 'Used' AND R.ServiceID = 2264
     )
SELECT r.ServiceID, SUM(r.Price) as Price,
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + rd2.ItemName
               FROM r r2 
               WHERE r2.ServiceId = r.ServiceId
               FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
              ).VALUE('.', 'varchar(max)'
                     ), 1, 2, ''
             ) as items
FROM r
GROUP BY r.ServiceID;
```

Comment: As a new comer can i ask what is this way of query in sql server ?? .By the way query showing in sql server 2014  "VALUE" is not a valid function, property, or field.

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash . . . `value()` is a method for the XML data type (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

Declare  @RequisitionDetail as table (serviceID int, itemname varchar(200), price float)

insert into @RequisitionDetail
        ( serviceID, itemname, price )
VALUES  ( 2264, -- serviceID - int
          'LCD', -- itemname - varchar(200)
          1500.00  -- price - float
          )

insert into @RequisitionDetail
        ( serviceID, itemname, price )
VALUES  ( 2264, -- serviceID - int
          'Touch Panel', -- itemname - varchar(200)
          1200.00  -- price - float
          )

insert into @RequisitionDetail
        ( serviceID, itemname, price )
VALUES  ( 2264, -- serviceID - int
          'Service Charge', -- itemname - varchar(200)
          250.00  -- price - float
          )

Select * from @RequisitionDetail

SELECT R.ServiceID,
       SUM(Price) as Price,
       itemname = (Select Replace(Replace(Replace((Select itemname from @RequisitionDetail x where x.serviceID = r.serviceID for xml path),'','' ),'',','),'',''))
  FROM @RequisitionDetail r
 GROUP BY R.ServiceID

Comment: There are lot more data which demands dynamic solution not as explicit table in my case

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer with the help of Gordon Linoff and this link

[Concatenate Select in t-sql](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

I have done it by creating a user defined function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_select_concat ( @ServiceId BIGINT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @p VARCHAR(MAX) ;
           SET @p = '' ;
          select @p=@p+X.ItemName+',' from
        (
        SELECT  R.ServiceID,ItemName, Price 
        FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
        WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=@ServiceId 
        ) X
RETURN @p
END
```

and finally

```
SELECT  R.ServiceID,SUM(Price) as Price,dbo.udf_select_concat(R.ServiceID) as Items--,ItemName, Price 
FROM RequisitionDetail RD, Requisition R 
WHERE RD.ItemStatus='Used' AND RD.RequisitionID=R.RequisitionID AND R.ServiceID=2264
GROUP BY R.ServiceID
```

results

```
ServiceID   Price   Items
2264       2950.00  LCD,Touch Panel,Service Charge,
```

There are other ways.But take data in code behind in c# and concatenate causes performance issues.So i prefer to do things in sql server not in code behind file manupulation.